# How to connect Oracle DB to iOS app

Tags: ios, database, oracle

I'm trying to develop an app for iOS in which I show some informations and graphs, that i retrieve from an Oracle DB. The question is now how can I create a connection between my app and the Oracle DB and is it then possible to use this data from the DB to create graphs?

Minor question: is there any possibility to create an application using something like Oracle APEX.

Many thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't connect oracle database  to iOS app. In iOS only SQLite database is used.

**If you want to access data which is in oracle database or in any other database, then you have to use web service.**

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer. So the only possibility I have to connect the app to the oracle db is through a web service. But can you please explain me how i can use a web service to connect to the DB? And how can I create this web service?

Comment: sorry, I don't have any knowledge of creating web service and in case of using web service , you will find many tutorials on internet which helps you.